# Removing columns coded by -,N or ? in Alignments

Tags: python, alignment, fasta

I was wondering if there is a method using perl or python to remove columns from MSA that have only gaps - and/or N and/or ? (everything except a nucleotide). It will be to run it on several MSA.

> seq1
>   ATCGNN-??ATCG
>   seq2
>   ATCGNN--ATCGCG
>   seq3
>   ATCG-?NCGAAAAA

(Remove columns 5,6,7)

I know that there is some tool like TrimAl who has the option to remove gappy positions but I dont know if I can adapt it to look at positions with only characters '-' 'N' '?'. I want to keep ?,N,- in others part of the alignments, so I don't think that the command tr can help?

Thank you

Comment: Hi can you share some more details please ?

Comment: hi, yes here is maybe a better example:

Comment: hi, yes here is maybe a better example:   
`seq1 ATCG-----NN-----ATCG    
seq2   ATCG--??---NNNATNG    
seq3   ATCC????????ATCG 
seq4   ATCG---------NNATCG  `  

In some of my alignments I have big gaps block created which only contain the characters "-" "N" "?". I looking for a way to remove this block, but without changing "N" and "?" as "-" because i want to keep these characters in others parts of the alignments (where it not a big gap block). TrimAl only work if the gap are made of "-".